# Why do Windows laptops auto-shutdown at 5% battery and not 0%?

Tags: windows, laptop, battery

Why do laptops shut down when their battery is **almost** empty? I'm basing my facts on Windows machines, but they always seem incapable of going past 5% without shutting down.

*(Because smartphones on the other hand, seem to be able to go the whole way to 0% before shutting down. Most of them seem to still have a small amount of "reserve" power at the declared "0%" value. I guess that it rounds down, so ~0.4% would be 0%. I'm pretty sure iOS does the same as well.)*

So, Why do laptops (especially on Windows) shut down on 5% and don't run until they die by default?  Is there a factual reason for this?  For example, do laptops have a sufficiently complex shutdown process (in which the system can lack the ability to do so if the battery power is too low)?

Comment: Laptop still need to write to a disk in order to shut down, If they risking going to 0% they could lakc the power do do that and leave the filesystem in an inconsistent state. Meanwhile phones usually do not have rotating rust.  So a >0% default on laptops seems reasonable.

Comment: On Android, most devices have a reserve at the declared "0%" value, and consumers expect to be able to run down devices to 0% and shut down gracefully. The same is not necessarily the case for Windows laptops.

Comment: Most of the time this can be changed if you want to run your battery all the way down, not recommended but it's there.  In Power Options->Edit Plan Settings->Advanced Power Options, at the bottom is a battery section where you can change what the Critical, Low, and Reserve battery levels and actions.

Comment: There are several things going on.  Part is the need for a little reserve power, what Hennes describes.  Part is in what the 7% or 0% mean, what bwDraco describes.  It's like the tare weight on a scale.  That percentage doesn't necessarily show actual battery condition, it's more like "usable range".

Answer (score 2):

It is a default setting in the OS.

In Windows, you can change that in the settings, there are three thresholds - the first to give you an initial warning, the second to issue a final warning, and the third to sleep or shut down the computer.

For all three of them, you can set what is supposed to happen, and if you like, you can set the shutdown to 0%, or set it to do nothing; that way, the computer will run until it dies.

It is not recommendable though, as most OS installations have a chance to be wrecked by a sudden power loss. I have mine set at 1%, though, and that works fine; but YMMV.

Comment: I'm not asking how to change it, I'm asking why it happens. Why are those thresholds set as they are?

Comment: Because Microsoft thought that would be good for us?